# Taming the VW-Unit (CSS)

Tags: html, css, font-size, viewport-units

I've sized practically all of my project using units of vw, including fonts. Works great, seamless transition to different window sizes and devices-- except, at a certain width (or height), I want everything to stop growing.

Setting a max-width on a parent wrapper doesn't do it. I can set a max-width on all my divs, but attributes like font-size will continue to grow.

Is there a simple way to tell everything to stop expanding when the project reaches a certain size?

The only path I see forward is selecting every element and instructing them all individually, via max-width & media queries... Seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528290 should solve your problem I guess..

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah, media queries on the fonts. I'm guessing this is part of what I'll have to end up doing. It just seems like my problem is the sort of thing there might be a one-liner of all-encompassing code for. Perhaps not. Thanks