# html: max function in font-size doesn't work

Tags: html, css

can anyone tell me what is wrong about this code:

```
<p id="text" style="font-size: max(6vh, 6vw);" />
```

the html inspections says invalid value. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement max-font-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528290/how-to-implement-max-font-size)

Answer (score 3):

`max()` ist experimental and only works in Safari

See the Documentation on MDN: [`max()` #Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max#Browser_compatibility)